# How to use Loop Stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a classes table in which I need to run stored procedure (SQL Server) in loop of class i.e., it should run 5 times here because maximum class in 5th standard in table. On every loop status field should update as pass or fail.

Kind of table is mentioned below.

Table Name: `classes`

[image]

Stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;

SELECT count(class)
FROM classes
GROUP BY class;

WHILE @counter <= * * [here I need count of distinct class] * *;//i.e, here 5 
BEGIN
    PRINT @counter;

    UPDATE classes
    SET STATUS = "Pass"
    WHERE class = * * [here I need class value] * *;

    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

Please help me to run this stored procedure.

Comment: Why would you want to loop in the first place. SQL is a **query** language, not a programming language. You want to use set-based methods not iterative ones. What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This is just simply `UPDATE classes SET STATUS = 'Pass'` at the moment. What are you *really* trying to do.

Comment: @Larnu - it will be a large data which will run after setting job...

Comment: That doesn't explain why you want a loop. In fact, if it is a large dataset, looping through every row would be a ***huge*** mistake; it'll tank any performance you may have previously had. Again what are you *actually* trying to achieve? If this isn't an example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) I don't know what is.

Comment: You did not post a stored procedure. So if you really want to do this, then start by posting a complete procedure definition and not just some set of statements. Using roman numerals but interpreting as a number? That will likely become be a big problem! Lastly a <while counter loop> is just a poor cursor replacement. If you need a loop, just use a cursor. But chances are you don't need a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't just want an UPDATE statement?

```
UPDATE classes
SET [Status] = CASE WHEN [Class] = 'I' THEN 'Pass'
                    WHEN [Class] = 'II' THEN 'Fail'
.... etc.
```